Relationship between density and temperature - How to know the precise temperature at which a bell inside a Galileo Thermometer will sink?
A Galileo Thermometer consists of bells placed inside a tube that's filled with liquid. As the temperature increases, the fluid density decreases. This leads to a decrease in the buoyant force, and the bells start sinking one by one, depending on their weight. The heaviest bell of course sinks first.
The fluid density must be equal to that of the bell for the bell to sink.
My question is this: How do we know at which precise temperature (measured in Celsius) the density of the fluid will equal that of the object? In other words, how do we relate density to temperature?

There are tables and curves for the expansion coefficient of water in the net. But for the Galileo Thermometer it probably not calculated, but adjusted by the little weighs which show the temperature.
